# Compact Hot water tank - can cold water go on the to and hot water come out the side connections

Tags: hot-water

I am installing a space saver 6.5 tank

Is it ok to connect the cold to the top connection and use the side connection for the hot water out

Comment: "ok"? depends what you want. water stratifies.

Comment: The cold should go to the bottom. Hot water rises, so you draw the hot water at the top.

Comment: @RohitGupta used a tank to mix hot and cold to supply an underfloor system - reversed the connections to make use of stratification so supply to floor came out the middle not the top. So tank outlets can be used differently compared to "normal" expectations, but that is what engineers do...

Comment: Tanks usually have a cold inlet and a hot outlet marked.  They usually also have a separate connection for the pressure relief valve, but not always.  Plumbing pipes can be routed to where they are needed, so very rare to need to mix up the connections.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to fill it. Air is lighter than water. With the normal way of plumbing it, water enters the tank at the bottom, the tank fills, and air comes out via the hot water outlet at the top and exits through the faucet, until the tank is completely full with water. With the outlet at the bottom, there is no way for air to get out, so the tank will remain full of air, and the heating element will burn.

Even if the tank fills with water, there's also the issue that hot water rises. If someone uses all the hot water, the heating element will do its job and you get a layer of hot water at the top of the tank ready for use rather quickly. With the outlet at the bottom you'd have to wait until the whole tank has heated to get any.